# SLA Process For Custom Objects

Tags: apex, entitlements

SLA process can be introduced using Entitlement Processes for Cases. 
However I do not find any out of the box capability to implement this for other Custom Objects.
Can you please let me know how to go about doing this for Custom Objects?

Comment: See demo and app link to set timeline process for any object: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGCl1WjWrvo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entitlement Processes do not support custom objects, or any standard objects other than Case. I'd love it if Entitlement Processes could be used on leads, as our demand-management teams track response-time SLAs, but there is no prospect of that coming any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free application on the AppExchange that allows you to set SLAs on any object or field: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000GB0VkUAL

Disclosure: I work for the app developer. This was developed for several of our clients and we decided to release it to the community for free.

Comment: Hey Michael, welcome to SFSE! Could you make an [edit] to clarify whether or not you're affiliated with this product? Thanks.